# Testing JavaScript functions that's working with interactive DOM

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, javascript-framework

I want to write some js tests, but all test frameworks use fixtures - custom DOM elements. In my case, views - it's erb and haml files. After page load (when i compile arb and haml), my js script does many AJAX request to API and rebuild DOM on my page.

How can i test js scripts, that interact with this DOM - i can't do some fixtures...

Maybe, i can take DOM from my page?

Which framework allows it to do?

Comment: Since you're testing your DOM, this is not unit testing anymore. As Dominic points out, you probably want to look into integration tests. Or rethink your testing approach. Since the DOM needs to be rendered before it becomes the DOM, you can always test the rendered strings.

Comment: I must use stubs and mocks in unit testing and use custom fixtures?

Comment: I meant the DOM is something the browser provides. This is not scope of a unit test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few different options here.

I personally use [jasmin with the jquery plugin](https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery) to test the dom and javascript of my applications.

Or you could go down the more Qa style DOM testing using [selenium](https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery) or [easy B](http://code.google.com/p/easyb/)

Hope that helps

Comment: Can i load fixtures from page, for example, localhost/news with jasmin or selenium?

Comment: With selenium you dont need fixtures, selenium will access your application and then run your tests as if a user. With jasmine&jquery you can ajax load in pages from your app and select the areas you want as fixtures.